# How to run a function from an imported object?

Tags: javascript, odoo

I'm working with an odoo application. And I'm trying to implement a JavaScript (native) module to extend the functionality of an existing service.

So in `file_a.js` I have the following (mock code):

```js
function parentFunction(someArg) {
  function _internalFunction() {
    const someValue = 'some_value';
    return typeof someValue;
  }
}
export const mainAction = {
  dependencies: ['thingOne', 'thingTwo'],
  mainFunction(someArg) {
    return parentFunction(someArg);
  },
};
registry.category('services').add('action', mainAction); // this part is real code
```

In `file_b.js`, I'm importing the `file_a` as follows:

```js
import { mainAction } from 'path/to/file_a';

console.log(typeof mainAction)
// output of above is object
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(mainAction)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${typeof value}`);
}
// output of for loop above is: dependencies: object / mainFunction: function
// at this point I know "mainFunction" is a function
```

What I'm stuck with is 2 things:

1. How do I access what is being returned by `mainFunction`? In this case it would be `parentFunction`.
2. Once I have access to `parentFunction`, how do I access `_internalFunction`?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the value of `someValue` inside of `_internalFunction`.

Hopefully this makes sense.
Thank you all.

Comment: Try putting `return` in front of `mainFunction(someArg) {`.

Comment: Have not tried that yet. I'll do it to test. But unfortunately I cannot modify file_a.js as it is part of the core code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one thing should be changed in this code to get access to the internal function:

1. The `mainAction.mainFunction()` will return you a result of the execution of `parentFunction`, in the current implementation it will be `undefined` since `parentFunction` doesn't return anything.
2. To access the `_internalFunction`, you should return it from the parent function, like this:

```js
function parentFunction(someArg){
   return function _internalFunction(){
      const someValue = 'some_value';
      return typeof someValue;
   }
}
```

After this change, you are able to access the internal function:

```js
const internalFunction = mainAction.mainFunction()
internalFunction() // string
```

Comment: Thank you @Dmytro - Your proposed solution makes a lot of sense to me. I'll try it to confirm. I can't really use it though. Because I cannot modify the code in parentFunction, since it is part of the core code base. 
Not only I want to access it through an import statement. Overwriting it would be ideal.

Comment: The `_internalFunction` is defined in the `parentFunction`'s scope, so there is no other way to access it. However, since you have access to `mainAction`, it have an option for you to redefine the `mainFunction` function:


`mainAction.mainFunction = function(someArg) {
// your code here
}`

Such an approach does not pretend to be the best practice, and it is only an answer about how to override `mainFunction`

Comment: Thank you for following up. I really appreciate you taking the time to look at this. I can't really use your proposed solutions (for the integrity of the code base). But it is in fact what I would have used to solve my problem. I'll mark it as the accepted answer.